# Time complexity of casting lists to tuples in python and vice versa

Tags: python, list, casting, tuples, time-complexity

what is the time complexity of converting a python list to tuple (and vice versa):

```
tuple([1,2,3,4,5,6,42])
list((10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,1))
```

O(N) or O(1), i.e. does the list get copied or is something somewhere internally switched from writable to read-only?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, the original list could still be modified, so don't think it would work to simply switch from writable to read-only.  But you can look at the source and find out.  Or you can time it and see if it follows O(N).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an O(N) operation, tuple(list) simply copies the objects from the list to the tuple. SO, you can still modify the internal objects(if they are mutable) but you can't add new items to the tuple.

[Copying a list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) takes `O(N)` time.

```
>>> tup = ([1, 2, 3],4,5 ,6)
>>> [id(x) for x in tup]
[167320364, 161878716, 161878704, 161878692]
>>> lis = list(tup)
```

Internal object still refer to the same objects

```
>>> [id(x) for x in lis]
[167320364, 161878716, 161878704, 161878692]
```

But outer containers are now different objects. So, modifying the outer objects won't affect others.

```
>>> tup is lis
False
>>> lis.append(10)
>>> lis, tup
([[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6, 10], ([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6)) #10 not added in tup
```

Modifying a mutable internal object will affect both containers:

```
>>> tup[0].append(100)
>>> tup[0], lis[0]
([1, 2, 3, 100], [1, 2, 3, 100])
```

Timing comparison suggest list copying and tuple creation take almost equal time, but as creating a new object with new properties has it's overhead so tuple creation is slightly expensive.

```
>>> lis = range(100)
>>> %timeit lis[:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 us per loop
>>> %timeit tuple(lis)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 us per loop
>>> lis = range(10**5)
>>> %timeit lis[:]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.66 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tuple(lis)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.77 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, there's no *bit to switch*, as the list (mutable) object is completely different than the tuple (immutable) object. They have different methods etc.

One experiment you might do is this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b[2] = 'a'
>>> b
[1, 2, 'a', 4, 5]
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

See, if they were referencing the exact place in the memory then `a` should have changed as well.

That's for my understanding.

Comment: Of course they're referencing the same object, I didn't say it was a deep-copy, obviously it's a shallow-copy. But still a copy. That's what the OP asked about