# Adding and creating chunks of a list in python

Tags: python

This is my list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

i tried to do this

```
it = iter(list1)

chunked_lists =  zip(it,it,it)

chunked_lists is now = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)]
```

Now i'd like to add a 'data' to every chunk so that it would look like

```
[(1,2,3,'data'),(4,5,6,'data')....etc]
```

but tuples are immutable and i'd have to destroy them, append and create them again.

is there a better way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: Why do you need that exactly ? If your plan to add a lot more data to each chunk, maybe you could converter them to list after the zip.

Comment: Tobia Tesan's solution is more robust than the zip-based methods, since it handles the `len(list1)%3!=0` situation. FWIW, if I can **guarantee* that the list length is ok I'd probably just do `[u+('data',)for u in zip(*[iter(list1)]*3)]`. OTOH, I guess you could do something with `[i]zip_longest`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
it = iter(list1)
from itertools import repeat
chunked_lists =  zip(it,it,it,repeat("data"))
[(1, 2, 3, 'data'), (4, 5, 6, 'data'), (7, 8, 9, 'data'), (10, 11, 12, 'data')]
```

Comment: Excellent, there is no need to specify the number of repeat!

Comment: @Kasramvd, yep, it will just repeat as necessary

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why does `print repeat('data')` give the output as `repeat('data')` ???

Comment: @wolfgang, it is just how python represents the object.

Comment: @wolfgang, the formatting is here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L4168

Comment: @wolfgang: `repeat` produces an iterator that just produces the object forever (or a specific number of times if a second argument is given). It's not a `list` or sequence of any kind, so they just defined a `repr` form for it that shows you how to create it (which is pretty typical for `repr`s in general, when it's possible).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to create a new iterator contain the `data` and then apply the `zip` function on your prior iterators and new repeated iterator :

```
>>> it = iter(list1)
>>> it2=repeat('data',len(list1))
>>> chunked_lists =  zip(it,it,it,it2)
>>> chunked_lists
[(1, 2, 3, 'data'), (4, 5, 6, 'data'), (7, 8, 9, 'data'), (10, 11, 12, 'data')]
>>>
```

Note that as @Padraic Cunningham mentioned on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637688/2867928) there is no need to call the `len` function in `itertools.repeat`.So you can simply use `repeat('data')`

If you want to modify the list of tuples after creation you can use a list comprehension to modify your tuples by adding the new elements to the tuples.

Example :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l2=np.random.randint(0,100,len(list1)/3)
>>> it = iter(list1)
>>> chunked_lists =  zip(it,it,it)
>>> chunked_lists = [i+(j,) for i,j in zip(chunked_lists,l2)]
>>> l2
array([35, 22, 35, 95])
>>> chunked_lists
[(1, 2, 3, 35), (4, 5, 6, 22), (7, 8, 9, 35), (10, 11, 12, 95)]
>>>
```

Comment: I am not sure he plans to just add a 'data' to each of his chunk, my guess is it's a placeholder for something he's going to add later. (He might be doing it lot, as he seems concerned by computational cost of tuple creation)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a linear time way to do it:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
result = [tuple(list1[x:x+3]+["data"]) for x in range(0, len(list1), 3)]
```

If I am not ignoring some Python intricacy, [since tuple() has complexity O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726969/time-complexity-of-casting-lists-to-tuples-in-python-and-vice-versa), [the slice accessor has complexity O(k)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and the overhead caused by the `+["data"]` isn't greater than simply appending a node at the end of a list (which is `O(1)`), it should be `O((len(list1) / k) * k ^ 2)` aka `O(n k)`, where `k` is fixed to 3 in your case.

```
result = [tuple(list1[x:x+3]+["data"]) for x in range(0, len(list1), 3)]
```

means:

`[list1[x:x+3]+["data"] for x in (0, 3, ... 12)]`

aka:

```
[
 tuple(list1[0:3]+["data"]),
 tuple(list1[4:6]+["data"]),
 ...
 tuple(list1[9:12]+["data"])
]
```

It is also well behaved with odd lists:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
>>> print [tuple(list1[x:x+3]+["data"]) for x in range(0, len(list1), 3)]
[(1, 2, 3, 'data'), (4, 5, 6, 'data'), (7, 8, 9, 'data'), (10, 11, 'data')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since tuples are immutable, if you're adding and deleting from them often, you're perhaps better off using lists of lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
it = iter(list1)
chunked_lists = [list(a) for a in zip(it,it,it)]  
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

for l in chunked_lists:
    l.append('data')
# => [[1, 2, 3, 'data'], [4, 5, 6, 'data'], [7, 8, 9, 'data'], [10, 11, 12, 'data']]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding them to the `zip` function when you are creating the `chunked_lists` itself -

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> it = iter(list1)
>>> chunked_lists =  zip(it,it,it,['data']*(len(list1)/3))
>>> chunked_lists
[(1, 2, 3, 'data'), (4, 5, 6, 'data'), (7, 8, 9, 'data'), (10, 11, 12, 'data')]
```

---

For Python 3.x , you would need to divide the `len(list1)` using `//` operator (for it to return int) . (And most probably wrap `zip` in `list()` , since `zip` in Python 3.x , returns an iterator.)