# How to create a chunked list of tuples of size 500 and then add data to it?

Tags: python

This is my code, using Python 2.7

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10.....1000]
```

I'm trying to create chunks of 500 list data like this

```
chunk_data = [(1,2,3,4,5,...500),(501,502....1000)]
```

and then I'm going to add a "data" at the end of each chunk

so it will look like this

```
[(1,2...500,'data'),(501,502...1000,'data')]
```

I tried to use zip for this

```
it = iter(list1)    
chunked_data = zip(*[it]*500)
```

but I'm unable to append the "data" now

```
from itertools import repeat
chunked_data = zip(*[it]*500,repeat("data")) #Gives Error about adding arguments after unpacking function values !!
```

It's not possible for me to write this code below even though it would work

```
chunked_data = zip(it,it,it...(500 times),repeat("data")]
```

So how should I attempt this?

Comment: Tuples are immutable, and can't be appended to.  So, even if this code worked, it would need to copy and be very inefficient.  If your goal is to re-use the list1 somehow, consider using a better data structure.  If you don't intend to re-use it, consider using a loop that does something special when ((i+1) % 500 == 0) (or, more advanced, list comprehensions or generators).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham segregate the input array into chunks of 500 elements

Comment: what if the array is not evenly divisible by 500?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That would'nt happen in the case of the input

Comment: This is a follow-on question to [Adding and creating chunks of a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31637486/4014959)

Comment: @wolfgang: Why do you like `zip` so much? What are the advantages I'm missing? (Disadvantages I can see: poor readability).

Comment: @wolfgang: also, do you really *need* (immutable) tuples? You seem to be doing an awful lot of manipulations with those (see also: [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31637486/4014959))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a list of positional arguments and then unpack it:

```
args = [it] * 500 + [repeat('data')]
chunked_data = zip(*args)
```

This is essentially a modified [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` documentation.

It works nicely:

```
In [17]: it = iter('0123456789')

In [18]: args = [it] * 5 + [repeat('data')]

In [19]: list(zip(*args))
Out[19]: [('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'data'), ('5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'data')]
```

---

Alternative solution:

```
[tuple(list1[i:i+500]) + ('data',) for i in range(0, len(list1), 500)]
```

You can find more at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/2301450) page.

Comment: @AnandSKumar because this is a bad answer?

Comment: I mean the reason why this is a bad answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[tuple(list1[i:i+500]+['data']) for i in xrange(0, len(list1), 500)]
```

You can change 500 and extend it for any chunk size

Comment: OP needs tuple inside :p

Comment: Thanks @itzmeontv. Fixed it.

Comment: [Oddly familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31637605/3881403) :)
OP should note that for very large `k` (`500` is probably not yet *very* large) the overhead can become significant compared to an iterator-based way.

Answer (score 1):

Function which provides your output

```
def chunks_with_data(l, n):
    return [tuple(l[i:i + n])+("data",) for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

>>>chunks_with_data(range(1000), 500)
```

Comment: This solution has come up an inordinate number of times, but +1 for being the first to parametrize `n`, which at this point seems a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

But it might be very very long!!

```
base_lst = [x for x in range(1, 1001)]
lst = [tuple(base_lst[x:x+500]+['Data']) for x in range(500)]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Your response have one problem though. It would iterate over every element in the list and add the next 500 elements. What OP clearly wanted was getting tuples like (1...500), (501...1000), not (1...500), (2...501).

Comment: @wswld: Well… He said "chunks of 500 list data like this" So, for me it's 500 `tuple` in a `list`. No?

Comment: It seems that he himself illustrated it like that: chunk_data = [(1,2,3,4,5,...500),(501,502....1000)].

Comment: Yes, but it seems to that is easier to forget a comma: '[(),,()]' than to make an error like confounding "500 list" with "2 lists". No?

Comment: And when he write: `it = iter(list1)` then `chunked_data = zip(*[it]*500)`, for me is to a 500 lists (here as an example). No? Don't you think so?

Comment: Well, at this point it becomes unclear what OP really meant, as he illustrated it both ways.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on this problem. It returns 500 element chunks from a list (`[(1...500),(501...1000)]`) and appends `data`:

```
l = [x for x in range(1, 1001)]
out_l = [tuple(l[i:i+500] + ['data']) for i in xrange(0, len(l), 500)]
```