# Time complexity of converting tuple into a list (vice versa)

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

if we are have a list lst = [1,2,3,4] and we convert it to a tuple like this tup = tuple(lst), what will be the time complexity of this code?

Comment: What's preventing you from trying it yourself? https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time complexity of casting lists to tuples in python and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726969/time-complexity-of-casting-lists-to-tuples-in-python-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an O(N) operation, tuple(list) simply copies the objects from the list to the tuple.
so, you can still modify the internal objects(if they are mutable) but you can't add new items to the tuple

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(n) because the underlying operation is simply taking the original numbers and copying the objects into a tuple rather than a list.

Python list time complexity: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

| Operation | Average Case | Amortized Worst Case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Copy | O(n) | O(n) |

Comment: Well, the objects aren't copied but yeah it is O(n)

Comment: They are copied, if you look at the original object reference for values in the list compared to the ones in the tuple, it would be different - it is a shallow-copy and not a full deep copy but nonetheless the operation conducted in the underlying execution is copying.

Comment: No it isn't, *that's what a shallow copy means* btw. And no, the objects in the list and tuple are *identical*

Comment: A shallow copy constructs a brand new object and inserts the original object references into it, hence the operation still being a copy. https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html Sure it is not *copying* the base values used, but the reference to the object changes in a new copied tuple.

Comment: We are speaking past each other I think, all I'm saying is that the *objects in the list* are not copied. E.g. `l = [{'a':0}]; t = tuple(l); l[0]['a'] = 1; print(t[0])` will print `{'a':1}`